# Delete all files and folders not in a list

Tags: bash, shell-script

Given a text file containing paths that I want to keep like:

```
/mnt/cache/vfs/cf/A/file
/mnt/cache/vfs/cf/B/file2
```

And I want to clear everything else under `/mnt/cache/vfs/cf` unless it's in my text file

So `/mnt/cache/vfs/cf/Z/file3` is deleted, etc

The text file is huge, and has filenames with spaces and possible accents or other special characters

Comment: Do file names themselves contain newlines? If so, how are you delimiting filenames from each other?

Comment: The filenames are delimited by new lines i think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would list the files in the filesystem, remove those that exist in your set of files to be kept, and delete the remainder.

Here I've used NULL-terminated filenames throughout so that there is no confusion with `xargs` between a filename containing spaces and its space separated parts:

```
find /mnt/cache/vfs/cf -type f -print0 |
    LC_ALL=C sort -z |
    LC_ALL=C comm -z -23 - <(LC_ALL=C sort list-of-files-to-keep.list | tr '\n' '\0') |
    xargs -0 printf '%s\n' {}
```

Replace `printf '%s\n'` with `rm --` when you are ready to perform the deletions.

The `comm` command takes two sorted files and compares them line by line. The first column of output is entries only in the first file, the second is entries only in the second file, and the third is entries in both files. The `-1`, `-2`, and `-3` qualifiers inhibit output of the corresponding column, so our `comm -23` will output lines that are present only in the first file (`-`, i.e *stdin*).

I've forced the locale to `C` so that `sort` and `comm` work in a consistent manner with each other (`comm` requires sorted input), and also so that every line is sorted in deterministic manner (some locales sort sets of characters the same, so the characters in such a set may be ordered in an inconsistent way).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
shopt -s extglob
cd /mnt/cache/vfs/cf
{   printf 'rm !('; awk -F'/mnt/cache/vfs/cf' '{print $2}' file |
    paste -sd '|'
} | sed 's/$/)/'
```

When you are happy with the output, you can pipe the whole snippet in `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
cd /mnt/cache/vfs/cf
{   printf 'rm !('
    awk -F'/mnt/cache/vfs/cf' '{print $2}' file |
    paste -sd '|'
} | sed 's/$/)/' | 
    bash
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob
and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html

Comment: Sorry I realized I have already ran sed so the paths now are equal, and I Just need a way to get the list I have and delete things that are not in it. I edited my question, check again if it's clearer now. Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: It doesn't seem to delete anything. It just print the filenames. And I'm assuming ```file``` is my text file containing a path per line

Comment: Have you tested the second solution ending with `| bash` ?

Comment: Yes there is syntax error apparently

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple one-liner like this:

```bash
for FILE in $(ls /mnt/cache/vfs/cf); do grep "$FILE" keep_files.txt || rm "/mnt/cache/vfs/cf/$FILE"; done
```

---

But I would, depending on how many files you want to delete, recommend to always move them into a temporary directory, to make sure you don't remove a file you need by accident :)

Comment: The code is poor, sorry. (1) [Bash pitfall number one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). (2) [No quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). (3) Expanded `$FILE` you're giving to `grep` may look like a regular expression that matches more than you expect. Besides, `ls` will give you basenames, not full pathnames.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Oh wow, thanks for the website recommendation. And yeah I know, I still have a lot to learn how to write `Bash-Scripts` without any flaws. Thats why I said that he should move the files into a directory before deleting them. But yeah I can understand that you find this oneliner poorly written^^

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I only match the files I want to keep :( I have tried everything already and nothing works :(

Comment: @Freedo you haven't tried "_everything_", but you might have tried everything you can think of. There are (so far) two other answers here to consider

Comment: @ChrisDavies [What are comments for, and when shouldn't I comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/1287086)

Comment: Some simple improvements: 1. use `fgrep` to prevent interpreting as regex 2. use bash wildcard expansion. This did what I want: `for folder in *; do fgrep "$folder" /path/to/keep.txt || rm -rv "$folder"; done` As always, `echo` the results BEFORE you run `rm`!!